# Run a C++ executable in Matlab from SSH server

Tags: c++, matlab, ubuntu, ssh, server

I'm trying to run an executable, generated from C++ code, in Matlab.
To do this I use the command

> system('unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH; /home/Documents/ServerFolder/ExecutableFiles/program_23 argument');

where program_23 is the executable generated by the C++ code.
When I do that in Ubuntu, it works perfectly fine.

The problem arise when I do that from a SSH server (i.d. calling Matlab from a server, but running the exact same script that works in Ubuntu).
In particular, if I add

> [status,cmdout] = system('unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH; /home/Documents/ServerFolder/ExecutableFiles/program_23 argument');

I can see that status is different from 0, meaning a failure of the system command.

Does anyone have any idea on how to make this work?
Thank you

Comment: So you're saying that if you run it locally and run it when you are SSH'd into the *same* machine you have that error?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In both the cases I run it from the same laptop.
I thing that I forgot to mention is that the executable is generated always by a compilation from the laptop, never from the server.
Maybe this could be a reason for the failure; unluckily for now I was not able to generate the executable from the server, so I can't say if this is the reason.